# Javascript replace regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

In my application I use the javascript replace method with following regex:

```
replace(/\€/g,'$')
```

This code find € character and change it to $. But now I want to this code replace € and £ to $ character. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to define one of several characters, as well they dont need to be escaped.

```
'€ and £'.replace(/[£€]/g, '$'); //=> '$ and $'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the OR operator to combine the pound and euro symbols (of which you do not need to escape). The resulting regex would be:

`/€|£/g`

Answer (score 1):

use this `replace(/[\€\£]/g,'$')` You can mention 2 or more characters in square brackets to match them individually.